# Multi-select list box in Cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cake php.I have to enter multiple city id in a database  with comma separator like 10,11,12 where 10,11,12 is city id

When I use this code

```
 **<?php
          echo $form->input('city_id', array('options' => $city, 'class'=>'input_box2',
'empty' => 'Please select a city'), null, array('id' => 'city_id', 'label' => 'City'
          ));**
```

I am able to insert one city id at a time,but i need to insert multiple city id with comma separator .
I am useing the following code but it is not working.please help

```
    **<?php
        echo $form->input('city_id', array('options' => $city, 'type'=>'select','multiple'
=> 'true', 'empty' => 'Please select  city'), null, array('id' => 'city_id', 'label' => 'City'));**
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify POST data in your controller:

in CakePHP 2.x

```
$city_ids = Set::extract('/YourModel/city_id', $this->request->data);        
$this->request->data['YourModel']['city_id'] = implode(",", $city_ids);
```

in CakePHP 1.x

```
$city_ids = Set::extract('/YourModel/city_id', $this->data);        
$this->data['YourModel']['city_id'] = implode(",", $city_ids);
```